# How to use material-ui in angular 7

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular7

I want to use material-ui in angular 7.I know that angular material is present.But I want to use ui-material instead of angular material.I don't know how to use it in angular

Comment: There is a plan within the Angular Google team to integrate MDC Web components into Angular Material components. This will hopefully provide the kind of out of the box UI components you might be looking for...like a range slider.

MDC Web -
[Github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) -
[Demos](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/)

Answer (score 3):

Material UI and Angular Material are both implementation of google material design. But Material UI is for react, while Angular Material is for Angular.

Comment: but material-UI for react have much better UI components than angular material UI

Answer (score 1):

Since Material Design Lite does not have any dependency, it's going to be easy to set up.
You can use your favorite tool to grab its source code.

> bower:  bower install material-design-lite --save  // using bower
>   npm:    npm install material-design-lite --save     // using npm

Next, we need to create an index.html file and include MDL's CSS file and JS files:

ex-

Now we can immediately use any of the MDL components.

Let's say we want to add a raised button with ripples, we just need to add the following to the body:

```html
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  Button
</button>
```

Comment: Material Design Lite is now in limited support, with development having moved to the Material Components for the web repository.